# Getting spring roo from repository

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, spring-roo

I am using eclipse kepler edition. I install eclipse sts plugin for kepler. But when I want to create a spring-roo project **in the dialog it say that there is no roo installation configured**. then I try to add  dependency from spring site

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.roo</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-roo</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

to my project pom file. but when i run command mvn clean package -U it say no dependency information available. I was looking for it on mvnrepository i cant find it and on findjar.com. It seems the spring foo **does not exist on repo.maven.apache.org/maven2**. I have no problem in getting other dependecy and every thing work fine except spring roo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure the following repository to access Spring Roo artifacts:
http://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org/release